# Is it possible to pass a function to an Ember.js component to execute it as an action callback?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a function as a parameter of an Ember component

```
// component.hbs
{{component fun=fun}}
```

and then, from an action in the component, calling this same function :

```
// component.js
actions: {
  fun2() {
     let fun = this.get('fun');
     fun();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. you can. what is the difficulty you are facing?. actually thats what happening when we use closure action.  refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/

Comment: Basically thats how closure actions work.

Comment: My issue here, was that I needed to extend my component to make this, your answers were useful !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/033860a542ddb126a73babad84feb9a6?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). What you are asking is valid and works. But in general you can pass a function to a component with an `action` helper and define your action within `actions` definition. What I can say is this is the common way of passing a function to a component and triggering an action (calling the function) from within the component.

### my-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    buttonClicked() {
      let foo = this.get('foo');
      foo();
    }
  }
});
```

### application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',

  foo() {
    alert('hi there');
  }
});
```

### application.hbs

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
<br>
{{outlet}}
{{my-component foo=foo}}
<br>
<br>
```

### my-component.hbs

```
<button onclick={{action 'buttonClicked'}}>Press</button>
```

Comment: Problem I have here is that `this` in undefined in the `foo` function so I cannot access anything in my controller, making the callback mostly useless.

Comment: are you sure you are using `action` helper?